# Fitting a Bezier Surface given a set of points

Tags: geometry

I have a set of data point and I want to generate Bezier Surface to fit it. Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer. I have a large amount of data points for the surface of the brain (I got it from STL file) . In contrary with the regular examples, I don't know how to segment them and How to choose the "u" and "v" parameters. I was thinking about using PCA techniques and using the largest eigenvalue directions as "u' and "v". However they are not separated surfaces, they finally should have continuity together. I would be so grateful if you have any suggestions.
Thank you,

Comment: You should probably use a b-spline surface, not a Bezier surface. The reference I gave tells you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to assign parameter values to the points. Then you set up a system of linear equations that express the fact that the surface passes through each of the given points. Solve these equations to get the control points of the surface. If you have a large number of points, you'll have too many equations, so you'll have to use least-squares fitting. The whole process is much easier if the points lie on a rectangular grid. See [this page](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/SURF-APP-global.html) for more info.